# How to set query parameter in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I want to use the [storybook-addon-react-router-v6](https://storybook.js.org/addons/storybook-addon-react-router-v6) add-on in Storybook to set query parameters and retrieve them with URLSearchParams. So I set the query parameters in searchParams as follows.

```
export const Example = () => <UserProfile />;
Example.story = {
  parameters: {
    reactRouter: {
      routePath: '/users/:userId',
      routeParams: { userId: '42' },
      routeHandle: "Profile",
      searchParams: { tab: 'activityLog' },
      routeState: { fromPage: 'homePage' },
    }
  }
};
```

The Storybook log shows the following, but URLSearchParams doesn't return the query parameters I set. Is there any solution?

```
Story rendered: {url: "/hoge?params=fuga", path: "/hoge", routeParams: Object, searchParams: Object, routeMatches: Array(1)...}
```